# How to iterate through dict in random order in Python?

Tags: python, random

How can I iterate through all items of a dictionary in a random order? I mean something random.shuffle, but for a dictionary.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A `dict` is an unordered set of key-value pairs. When you iterate a `dict`, it is effectively random. But to explicitly randomize the sequence of key-value pairs, you need to work with a different object that is ordered, like a list. `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()`, and `dict.values()` each return lists, which can be shuffled.

```
items=d.items() # List of tuples
random.shuffle(items)
for key, value in items:
    print key, value

keys=d.keys() # List of keys
random.shuffle(keys)
for key in keys:
    print key, d[key]
```

Or, if you don't care about the keys:

```
values=d.values() # List of values
random.shuffle(values) # Shuffles in-place
for value in values:
    print value
```

You can also "sort by random":

```
for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: random.random()):
    print key, value
```

Comment: In Python3, `d.items()`, `d.keys()`, and `d.values()` produce an iterator object. You need to explicitly convert that iterator to list using `list()` function.

Comment: "When you iterate a `dict`, it is effectively random" - it's not. Relying on it to even look random would be a bad idea, considering that things like ints are pretty likely to come out in sorted order. Also, the random-key sort is O(nlog(n)) instead of O(n), so it should probably be avoided.

Comment: How would you adapt this to always shuffle the dictionary (maintaining the links between the right key to the right value in the same way for example using `np.random.RandomState(100)`?

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Get the list of keys with `.keys()`, shuffle them, then iterate through the list while indexing the original dict.

Or use `.items()`, and shuffle and iterate that.

Comment: Or `dict.values()` if all you want is the values.

Comment: Can't or Won't? `for item in random.sample(list(d.values()), len(d)):`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def main():

    CORRECT = 0

    capitals = {'Alabama': 'Montgomery', 'Alaska': 'Juneau',
        'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'Arkansas': 'Little Rock'} #etc... you get the idea of a dictionary

    allstates = list(capitals.keys()) #creates a variable name and list of the dictionary items
    random.shuffle(allstates) #shuffles the variable

    for a in allstates: #searches the variable name for parameter
        studentinput = input('What is the capital of '+a+'? ')
        if studentinput.upper() == capitals[a].upper():
            CORRECT += 1
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a quick way for stepping through a shuffled list, so I wrote a generator:

```
def shuffled(lis):
    for index in random.sample(range(len(lis)), len(lis)):
        yield lis[index]
```

Now I can step through my dictionary `d` like so:

```
for item in shuffled(list(d.values())):
    print(item)
```

or if you want to skip creating a new function, here is a 2-liner:

```
for item in random.sample(list(d.values()), len(d)):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

As [Charles Brunet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621944/charles-brunet) have already said that the dictionary is random arrangement of key value pairs. But to make it really random you will be using random module.
I have written a function which will shuffle all the keys and so while you are iterating through it you will be iterating randomly. You can understand more clearly by seeing the code:

```
def shuffle(q):
    """
    This function is for shuffling 
    the dictionary elements.
    """
    selected_keys = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(q):
        current_selection = random.choice(q.keys())
        if current_selection not in selected_keys:
            selected_keys.append(current_selection)
            i = i+1
    return selected_keys
```

Now when you call the function just pass the parameter(the name of the dictionary you want to shuffle) and you will get a list of keys which are shuffled. Finally you can create a loop for the length of the list and use `name_of_dictionary[key]` to get the value.

Comment: You'd be far better off using an off-the-shelf shuffling or permutation function, like `numpy.random.permutation()`. But if you really want to do this yourself, this seems like a very slow way to shuffle the keys! Let's say you have a dict with 10k keys, and you are down to the last key. Imagine how many failed tries you will have to go through before you select it! To improve your algorithm, you could remove each selected key from the candidates in each iteration, so that you select only from the remaining keys.