# What's wrong with this code Python 3.3

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I'm trying to create a small Python program which calls a random student in lessons then it removes this student from the list till all other students are called.

Example :

> 1. ME
> 2. You
> 3. Others

I want to call randomly one and then remove it from the list so the next time it would be only

> 1. You
> 2. Others

I've wrote this code but it keeps repeating students without first calling all of them.

```
    import random
    klasa = {1 :'JOHN', 2 : 'Obama' , 3 : 'Michele' , 4 : 'Clinton'}

    ran = []

    random.seed()

    l = random.randint(1,4)

    while l not in ran:
        ran.append(l)
        print(klasa[l])

    for x in ran:
       if x != None:
           ran.remove(x)
        else:
           break
```

Comment: Why do you add just to remove?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So when all the list is called remove and start over.

Comment: This code doesn't demonstrate the error.

Comment: @user2357112 It has no error on syntax but it has a logic error because i want it to call all the elementes from the dict then repeat but it repeats same student without before calling all the other 
Hope to be clear!!!

Comment: No, I mean when you run this code, it doesn't repeat any students. Did you screw up the indentation?

Comment: Probably...
When commented but here when i run it 
comes 
Example:
John
Obama
JOhn

I want it to diplay all the other students then restart...

Comment: Don't ADD or REMOVE any item in a `for` loop.

Comment: It seems you just want to iterate in random order. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785672/how-to-iterate-through-dict-in-random-order-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take. One is to have a list of keys in the dictionary, select a key randomly from this list and then remove it. This would look like this:

```
from random import choice

keys = klasa.keys()
while keys: #while there are keys left in 'keys'
    key = choice(keys) #get a random key
    print("Calling %s" % (klasa.pop(key))) #get the value at that key, and remove it
    keys.remove(key) #remove key from the list we select keys from
```

`klasa.pop(key)` will return the value associated with the key in addition to deleting it:

```
 |  pop(...)
 |      D.pop(k[,d]) -> v, remove specified key and return the corresponding value.
 |      If key is not found, d is returned if given, otherwise KeyError is raised
```

Another approach is to shuffle the list of keys before hand and go over each one, i.e:

```
from random import shuffle

keys = klasa.keys()
shuffle(keys) #put the keys in random order
for key in keys:
    print("Calling %s" % (klasa.pop(key)))
```

---

If you want to delete people one person at time, you can simply do:

```
print("Calling %s" % klasa.pop(choice(klasa.keys())))
```

Though this means you will generate a list of the keys each time, it's better to store this in a list and remove the keys from this list as you delete them like in the first suggested method.  `keys = .keys() ... a_key = choice(keys), klasa.pop(key), keys.delete(key)`

*Note:* In python 3.x you need to go `keys = list(klasa)` as `.keys` doesn't return a list like 2.x

Comment: Ty for the answer and explanation but running it on python 3.3 shows and dictonary indexing error...

Comment: @KillerB see the note

Comment: `keys` returns a dict view in 3.x; just use `list(klasa)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for simplicity:

```
>>> klasa = ['JOHN', 'Obama' , 'Michele' , 'Clinton']
>>> random.seed()
>>> l = len(klasa)
>>> while l > 0:
...     i = random.randint(0,l-1)
...     print (klasa[i])
...     del klasa[i]
...     l=len(klasa)
... 
Michele
JOHN
Obama
Clinton
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify this Solution According to your Needs

```
from random import *

klasa = {1 :'JOHN', 2 : 'Obama' , 3 : 'Michele' , 4 : 'Clinton'}

#Picks a random Student from the Dictionary of Students 
already_called_Student=klasa[randint(1,4)]
print "Selected Student is" ,  already_called_Student
total_Students = len(klasa)
call_student_number = 0

while  call_student_number < total_Students:
    random_student=klasa[randint(1,4)]
    if random_student == already_called_Student:
        continue
    print random_student 
    call_student_number =   call_student_number  + 1
```