# Printing K and V in random range 2-4 from a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so I have a dictionary:

```
stock = {
 'GOOG':520.54,
 'FB': 76.45,
 'YHOO':39.28,
 'AMZN': 306.21,
 'AAPL': 99.76,
}
```

I would like it to print a random number of Keys with Values (Between 2-4).
Here is an example of what I did for a list to give you an idea.

```
items = ['Medkit', 'Water', 'Food', 'Gold',
     'Ammo', 'Beer', 'LSD']

print(random.choices(population=items, k=random.randrange(2, 5)))
```

I dont know how to codes this to spew out something like this for a dictionary with values and keys.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It's unclear exactly what you are looking for... can you provide a [mcve], including your expected output?

Comment: Be careful since dictionaries are unordered in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326729/5881884

Comment: I think this is nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785672/how-to-iterate-through-dict-in-random-order-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer** (ensures no duplicates)

First get a list of the keys in the dictionary (note this needs to be converted to a `list` or the next step won't work). Next, use `random.shuffle()` to shuffle this list of keys and ensure a random order. Then simply use the first 2–4 keys in the shuffled list to create a new random dictionary, which you can print. Note that this method ensures the 2–4 random keys chosen are unique (unlike methods using `random.choice()` or `random.choices()`, which can produce duplicates).

```
my_keys = list(stock.keys())
random.shuffle(my_keys)
my_stock = {key: stock[key] for key in my_keys[:random.randrange(2,5)]}
print(my_stock)
```

Example outputs:

```
{'GOOG': 520.54, 'AMZN': 306.21}
{'AMZN': 306.21, 'GOOG': 520.54, 'YHOO': 39.28}
{'AAPL': 99.76, 'AMZN': 306.21, 'YHOO': 39.28}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method items() on the dict will give you the key/value pairs e.g.

```
>>> stock.items()
[('GOOG', 520.54), ('YHOO', 39.28), ('FB', 76.45), ('AAPL', 99.76),
('AMZN', 306.21)]
```

So you could try:

```
print(random.choices(population=list(stock.items()),k=random.randrange(2, 5)))
```

Comment: In Python 3 this gives `TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`

Comment: `stock.items()` is acutally `dict_items[('GOOG', 520.54), ...]` in Python 3. You should indicate this in your answer.

Comment: This method can produce duplicates, e.g. `[('GOOG', 520.54), ('YHOO', 39.28), ('GOOG', 520.54)]`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get 2 to 4 random keys and their values.

What about this?

```
import random
for i in range(3):
    randomKey = random.choice(stock.keys())
    print(randomKey+" : "+stock[randomKey])
```

That's basically it. I have chosen 3 iterations of the for loop becasue you said, you want a number of 2 to 4 random keys. Of course you could check that no key appeares two times.

```
usedKeys = []
```

And later on check if your random key exists and if not, append it to the list.

Comment: In Python 3 this gives `TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing`